# Any good "training" or even "reference" books on kvm/libvirt?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, libvirt

Does anyone know any good training or even reference books on kvm/libvirt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KVM and virtualization is a rather specialized topic, so don't expect to find much information about them.

There is, however, quite detailed documentation of KVM API in the kernel source tree. You can find it [here](https://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/virtual/kvm/api.txt). Furthermore, [this](https://lwn.net/Articles/658511/) article can serve as a getting started guide on Linux KVM API.

Yet a another source of knowledge is the actual source code for VMMs which rely on KVM, like [qemu](http://qemu.org). Particularly, have a look at i386 target [implementation](http://git.qemu.org/?p=qemu.git;a=tree;f=target-i386;hb=HEAD).